# How to solve for m given that: 1/(1+m) = (1−m) +...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve for m given that:
$$ \frac{1}{1+m} = 1-m+ [m_1 ]$$
where $m_1$ is a correction that follows the same pattern as its parent i.e. 
$$ \frac{1}{1+m_1} = 1-m_1+[m_2] $$
and so on...
$$ \frac{1}{1+m_2} = 1-m_2+[m_3] $$

all m, $m_i$ <1 and $m_i$ are all successive corrections. And a follow up question is: is it possible to get a generalized solution to go deeper -- up to $m_i$? I guess I am trying to write the equation for m that follows the above pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the standard [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) result
$$\frac 1{1+m}=1-m+m^2-m^3+\ldots$$
The general term is $(-1)^im^i$

You can certainly write
$$\frac 1{1+m}=1-m+\frac {m^2}{1+m}\\
m_1=\frac{m^2}{1+m}\\
\frac 1{1+m_1}=\frac 1{1+\frac{m^2}{1+m}}=\frac {1+m}{1+m+m^2}=1-\frac{m^2}{1+m+m^2}$$

Comment: My answer is not in exactly the form you wrote, but I think it is more useful.  It shows the successive terms, but not as the inverse of one plus the previous correction.  As long as $|m| \lt 1$ the series converges.  It converges more quickly the smaller $m$ is.  Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your method the answer I got was about .015% or so off. Using spreadsheet and the methodology I use gives the accurate answer -- but I was hoping to get a mathematical formula -- like the one you suggest but more accurate (if possible) -- rather than use of spread sheet.

Comment: For now I am having to use spread-sheet and trial/error method to arrive at the correct answer and the trial error seems to suggest corrections in ways that I have outlined in the query.

Comment: thanks for the help.